# How to loop through a map and assign the value to an array in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a `map<id,age>,`; how to get the age of each `<id,age>` pair, and assign the age to a C-style array in C++?

what is the efficient way to do it? I mean how to fill the C-style array in the same order as map?

Comment: sorry, not map to vector, it is to array

Comment: @ratzip: Don't use arrays. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: I want to use vector, but other people defined it as array

Comment: i just updated my sample to _also_ show how it's done for auto/dynamic arrays http://ideone.com/Kf2du

Comment: have you already read my advice from your other question to finally get an introductory C++ book? all your questions are about very basic C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you decide to stick with the fixed array approach**

```
//Assuming both id and age are integers
map<int,int> myMap; // Your id and age map
map<int,int>::iterator it;
int myList[100];
int i = 0;
for(it = myMap.begin(); (i < 100 && it != myMap.end()); it++)
{
  myList[i++] = (*it).second;
}
```

**A MUCH better approach is to use a vector instead of an array**

```
//Assuming both id and age are integers
map<int,int> myMap; // Your id and age map
map<int,int>::iterator it;
vector<int> myList;
for(it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++)
{
  myList.push_back((*it).second);
}
```

Comment: sorry, it is a array, not a list

Comment: @ratzip vectors are like arrays, but better

Comment: @ratzip then you need to dynamically allocate the array based on the map size. Will edit answer in a sec.

Comment: the array size if fixed, it is 100, but the data to be filled is just 20, the rest is just for future use

Comment: @ratzip you need to be careful not to go out of bounds in that case since your map might have more than 100 entries.

Comment: @ratzip Also I really think you should reconsider using vectors instea of arrays.

Comment: @P.R I really want to use vectors, but this fixed array is designed by some senior, and I just try to implement the function using that data type

Answer (score 2):

If you can use c++11 you can use a lambda expression.

```
map<id,age> m;
std::list<age> l;
std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [&l](std::pair<id,age> p){
    l.push_back(p.second);
});
```

Comment: it means that the Lambda will capture the local variable l by reference

Comment: @sehe: cheers for straighten me out :) .. looking at it again it feels obvious.. every day you learn something new... except sundays..

Comment: `std::transform` would seem like a better candidate.  While this sounds more like homework, I would imagine that most professionals already have an "extractor" functional object, that given a structure, returns one member of it: in this case, you'd instantiate it to return the member `second`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're asking makes a lot of sense, but in the interest of just fiddling with C++ containers

(Note:: not using any C++0x features) **http://ideone.com/Kf2du**

**Edit** In response to the excellent comments by David Rodríguez, I have edited the code to avoid copying (see also https://ideone.com/7Oa5n):

```
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

typedef std::map<std::string, int> map_t;

int getage(const map_t::value_type& pair)
{ 
    return pair.second; 
}

int main()
{
     map_t agemap;
     agemap["jill"] = 13;
     agemap["jack"] = 31;

     std::list<int> agelist(agemap.size());
     std::transform(agemap.begin(), agemap.end(), agelist.begin(), getage);

     // or:
     std::vector<int> v;
     std::transform(agemap.begin(), agemap.end(), std::back_inserter(v), getage);

}
```

By popular demand, and just to *spell it out*:

```
int age_array[10];
std::transform(agemap.begin(), agemap.end(), age_array, getage);
```

or even

```
int *dyn_array = new int[agemap.size()];
std::transform(agemap.begin(), agemap.end(), dyn_array, getage);

// ...
delete[] dyn_array;
```

Comment: OP wants to move the elements to a C-style array.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Ok, I spelled out the trivial example to work with an array.

Comment: There is an interesting small detail that sometimes goes undetected in this answer. The `std::map<std::string,int>::value_type` is `std::pair<const std::string,int>`, rather than `std::pair<std::string,int>`. The implication of that is that, because the former can be converted to the latter, the `transform` loop will create a `std::pair<std::string,int>` temporary for each element in the map, and then bind the constant reference used as argument to it. Which in turn means that you are copying all the elements at least once in the operation.

Comment: Additionally, with boost, in C++03 you can do: `std::transform( agemap.begin(), agemap.end(), array, boost::bind( &std::map<std::string,int>::value_type::second, _1 ) );` for a single-liner.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: (re: 1st) astute point. Do you think that applied in my code (I don't know for sure, but I do know that the `getage` function doesn't implicitely force the copy (taking the `const` pair by ref); It could happen due to the fact that the non-const versions of `.begin()` and `.end()` are being preferred?)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: (re: 2nd) that may be true, but not necessarily very readable. I was trying to match the level of the question there. Also, you could of course make your points into a little answer of your own. The 'oneline fix' type of answer has it charm, you know.

Comment: @sehe: (re: 2nd) I don't think that it has enough content for an answer, but feel free to include it in yours if you think it will make it more complete. (re: 1st) With non-const iterators, `map<K,V>::value_type` is `pair< const K, V >`, note the extra `const`, now, the issue is that you have `void f( pair<K,V> const & )`, and that reference cannot be bound to a `pair<K,V>` (different template instantiations are unrelated types). The compiler tries to do as you ask, as hard as possible and finds a way by creating copies. Check this [test](http://www.ideone.com/s7e8F)

Comment: If the const versions of the overloads were used, the effect would be the same, you still have `void f( pair<K,V> const & )` and dereferencing the iterator will yield a `const pair<const K,V>`, again no match, again copies. If you just change the signature of `getAge` to `int getAge( const std::pair< const std::string, int > & )` then the types will match, and the reference will bind the object inside the map, with no copies (I have just changed the link to the test for another that tests both variants). [Hint: If you correct the `getAge` signature you will get my upvote :)]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: splendid. Much appreciated the very sound code sample (spares me the effort of demoing it to myself!). I will immediately see to it as that the answer gets fixed. In fact it will be one of them things I won't be forgetting to do anymore. Cheers

Comment: +1, as promised. Maybe you want to review the test that you linked, the two `getAge` variants are exactly the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3914/discussion-between-sehe-and-david-rodriguez-dribeas)

Answer (score 0):

You've stated you want a C array and I'll answer particularly your request.

```
  std::map<int,int> some_map;

  int * c_array=new int[some_map.size()];
  size_t k=0;
  for (std::map<int,int>::iterator i=some_map.begin();
       i != some_map.end(); ++i)
    {
      c_array[k++]=(*i).second;
    }
  delete[] c_array;
```

As others have stated, the standard for C++ would be the vector.  I would add, you would want to reserve the proper space before-hand since you already know it.  It can be reserved via the c-tor for a vector.

```
  std::map<int,int> some_map;
  std::vector<int>  some_vector(some_map.size());
  for (std::map<int,int>::iterator i=some_map.begin();
       i != some_map.end(); ++i)
    {
      some_vector.push_back((*i).second);
    }
```